# add a special character to a text field in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I want to add a special character to a textfield .
For example I want to add `/` automatically between a date that user typed.
Or adding some space between some digits in a number .like this: "2020 2020 2020 2020"

I used this code but it doesn't work correctly .

```
textfield.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>(){
  @Override
 public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String t, String t1) {
       if(t1.length()==4 || t1.length()==9 || t1.length()==14){
          textfield.setText(t1+" ");
           System.out.println("space added");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i think you have to implement a method: changed().  http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html

Comment: Thank you.I forgot to write it here. But I wrote it in main program.So this is not my problem.

Comment: what is value of t1? Does it go inside the loop? If yes, did you try pressing tab after entering in text area or clicking outside of the textarea ? Does the method execute?

Comment: Your code works fine for me: it adds a space in the places I'd expect. Change the space to a visible character ("/" for example) and you'll see it. (It doesn't work so well if you delete characters though, for example when the length changes from 5 to 4...)

Comment: @ James_D Yes! you are right ! Thank you . But it adds special character in the end of string. Why ?

Comment: `textField.setText(t1+" ");` will add the space at the end of the string.

Comment: So I will have :4242424242424242" "" "" ".I want to have 4242 4242 4242 4242

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's adding the space just fine. I think the issue is that you want to move the carat position after adding the extra text. You can use `textfield.getCaratPosition()` to find the current position and `textfield.positionCarat(...)` to change it.

The logic is going to be quite complex though and depends greatly on what the user is doing and precisely how you want the text field to behave. E.g. what if the text is changing because the user deletes something? What about copy and paste?

Comment: Yes,you are right . It is so complex ! And there isn't any solution ?Is there any library for do it ? What do other programmers do ???!!